# Draw arrows from multiple nodes to one and join with a common line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have multiple blocks which should be connected to "base" block like in UML diagram with "extends" arrow, (I created this example just by drawing without TeX):

[image: example]

I'm trying to do it using this code with `|-` for common line for arrows and `(270:10mm)` to move it down  for `10mm`:

```
\tikzset{node distance=1.6cm, auto, every text node part/.style={align=center, font={\sffamily\small}}}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=myblack, fill=white, inner sep=0.3cm, outer sep=0.1cm, thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[block] (base) {Base};
  \node[block, below=of base] (impl2) {Impl2};
  \node[block, left=of impl2] (impl1) {Impl1};
  \node[block, right=of impl2] (impl3) {Impl3};
  \draw[->] (impl1.north) |- (270:10mm) --++ (base.south);
  \draw[->] (impl2.north) |- (270:10mm) --++ (base.south);
  \draw[->] (impl3.north) |- (270:10mm) --++ (base.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I'm getting this picture:

[image: result]

How to join multiple arrows correctly with a common line? Most probably I'll need to change amount of blocks and the position of them, so fixed or hard-coded line coordinates won't work for me.

Comment: Like this? `\draw[->] (impl1.north) |- (270:10mm) -|  (base.south);
  \draw (impl2.north) --  (base.south);
  \draw (impl3.north) |- (270:10mm)  -| (base.south);`

Comment: In addition, to connect the edge to node, use `outer sep=0cm`.

Comment: Please complete your document to be a minimal *working* example. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. This saves a lot of time for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do like this, with `arrows` TikZ library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows}
\tikzset{
  node distance=1.6cm,
  auto,
  every text node part/.style={
    align=center,
    font={\sffamily\small},
  }
}
\tikzstyle{block}=[
  draw=black,
  fill=white,
  inner sep=0.3cm,
  outer sep=0cm,
  thick,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[block] (base) {Base};
  \node[block, below=of base]  (impl2) {Impl2};
  \node[block, left= of impl2] (impl1) {Impl1};
  \node[block, right=of impl2] (impl3) {Impl3};
  \draw (impl1.north) |- (270:10mm) -|  (base.south);
  \draw[-latex] (impl2.north) --  (base.south);
  \draw (impl3.north) |- (270:10mm)  -| (base.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** It is not a big problem but if you zoom in the arrow you will see that the connections coming from left and right nodes (which has no arrow) is changing the visual of the arrow tip. See below.

[image][image]

So, in this case, simply move down a little bit the end point of the connections with `([yshift=-1pt]base.south)`, for example, so the edge will not touch the frame and the arrow tip will be sharper.

```
  \draw (impl1.north) |- (270:10mm) -|  ([yshift=-1pt]base.south);
  \draw[-latex] (impl2.north) --  (base.south);
  \draw (impl3.north) |- (270:10mm)  -| ([yshift=-1pt]base.south);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I propose. A node `n` of shape `coordinate` is defined “at the crossroads” to make the code easy to read. The special arrow is done with the following style, which relies on the `arrows.meta` Ti*k*Z library:

```latex
extends/.style={->, >={Triangle[open, width=0.2cm, length=0.2cm]}}
```

Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Use `block/.style={...}` to define the `block` style (see below). `outer sep=0` in my `block` style ensures that connection lines don't stop before the rectangle border. I removed option `auto` because it isn't used here.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1.6cm,
  every text node part/.style={align=center, font={\sffamily\small}},
  block/.style={draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=0.3cm, outer sep=0, thick},
  extends/.style={->, >={Triangle[open, width=0.2cm, length=0.2cm]}},
  ]
  \node[block] (base) {Base} coordinate[below=0.7cm of base.south] (n);
  \node[block, below=of base] (impl2) {Impl2};
  \node[block, left=of impl2] (impl1) {Impl1};
  \node[block, right=of impl2] (impl3) {Impl3};

  \draw (impl1.north) |- (n);
  \draw (impl2.north) |- (n);
  \draw (impl3.north) |- (n);
  \draw[extends] (n) -- (base.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

Your diagram remains me on a tree with opposite arrow direction:

[image]

It can be simple drawn by use of the `forest` package with option `forked edge`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw,
    inner sep = 3mm,
    font = \sffamily\small,
% tree
   forked edge,
   l sep = 12mm,   % vertical distances between nodes
fork sep = 6mm,    % distances to connection point
   s sep = 12mm,   % horizontal distances between nodes
edge ={Stealth-}
           }% end for tree
[Base
    [Impl1]
    [Impl2]
    [Impl3]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```